# Restart queue:work daemon laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5

I launched **sudo nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon** on my server with laravel 5.1, I have change smtp .env but it doesn't change, and I would try to restart queue:work daemon.
How Can I do this?

Comment: Are you launching queue daemon from crontab? simple `php artisan queue:restart` should do the trick.

Comment: thankyou! but why mail send still same smtp? :/

Comment: I had to reboot for my problem